# Deserialize amf binary format using amf3input in java

Tags: java, serialization, amf

I am trying to deserialize amf binary format using flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Input in java. but did not find the flow of deserialization. Can any help me by giving steps or code snippet?
I tried with bellow code.....but readObject() returns null......please help.

```
 package amfnew;

  import java.net.ServerSocket;
  import java.net.Socket;
  import flex.messaging.io.SerializationContext;
  import flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Input;
  import flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Output;
  import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
  import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;

  public class MainAmf {
   byte[] read(String aInputFileName){
   File file = new File(aInputFileName);
byte[] result = new byte[(int)file.length()];

try {
  InputStream input = null;
  try {
    int totalBytesRead = 0;

    input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    while(totalBytesRead < result.length){
      int bytesRemaining = result.length - totalBytesRead;

      int bytesRead = input.read(result, totalBytesRead, bytesRemaining); 
      if (bytesRead > 0){
        totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;
      }
    }
  }
  finally {
    input.close();
  }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {      
}
catch (IOException ex) {

}
return result;
}

 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    MainAmf ma= new MainAmf();
    byte[] amfBytes;
        amfBytes = ma.read("C:\\JavaApp\\AmfNew\\sample.amf");
    InputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(amfBytes);   
Amf3Input amf3Input = new Amf3Input(SerializationContext.getSerializationContext());
amf3Input.setInputStream(bais);

    while(true)
    {
        try
        {

            Object obj = amf3Input.readObject();
            System.out.println("Reading..");
            System.out.println(obj);
            if(obj!=null)
            {
                System.out.println(obj.getClass());

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get mine to work.  Here is an AmfDeserializer:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle;

import flex.messaging.io.SerializationContext;
import flex.messaging.io.amf.Amf3Input;
import flex.messaging.messages.AcknowledgeMessage;

public class AmfDeserializer
{

   /**
    * @param args
    * @throws IOException 
    * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
    */
   public static void main( String[] args ) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
   {
      if(null == args || args.length != 1)
      {
         usage();
         System.exit( 1 );
      }

      File f = new File(args[0]);
      if(f.exists() && f.canRead())
      {
         Amf3Input deserializer = new Amf3Input(   SerializationContext.getSerializationContext() );
         deserializer.setInputStream( new FileInputStream( f ) );
         Object o = deserializer.readObject();

         if(o instanceof AcknowledgeMessage)
     {
            AcknowledgeMessage ack = (AcknowledgeMessage)o;
            System.out.println(ack.getCorrelationId());
            System.out.println(ack.getClientId());
            Object myObj = ack.getBody();
            System.out.println( ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString( myObj, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE ) );
         }
      }
   }

   private static void usage()
   {
      System.out.println("args: absolute path to the .amf file");
   }
}
```